# Regex for odd money value

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that contains a odd money value. The string is:

`Daily interest charges #901 $ 17.2789 259.18 190.07/day`

The odd value is `$ 17.2789`

I am trying to create a regular expression that will get is, but not have a back reference. This is what I have come up with:

`(?:\\$\\s*?\\d{0,1,2,3}\\.\\d{0,1,2,3,4}\\s*?/?day)?`

This however will not compile. Everything in there seems reasonable to me? Any idea what might be wrong with it? I am using Java

EDIT

I have tried m.buettner suggestion of `\\$\\s*\\d*\\.\\d*`. I places it in the 3rd grouping below. This almost does it. Here is my full regular expression:

`(.*)\s?#(\s?\d{3,4})\s*(?:\$\s*\d*\.\d*)?((?:-|\()?\$?(?:\d{1,3}[ ,]?)*(?:\.\d+)\)?)\s*((?:-|\()?\$?(?:\d{1,3}[ ,]?)*(?:\.\d+)\)?).*`

The groups it pulls are:

1. Daily interest charges
2. 901
3. 9 259.18
4. 190.07

It is grouping 3 that is the issue. It contains one extra digit, the first `9`

Edit Edit

There was a space that was causing the issue, this did it:

`(?:\$\s*\d*\.\d*\s)?`

Comment: Your quantifiers (e.g. `{0,1,2,3}`) don't look correct, unless that's some variation I'm not familiar with.  The quantifier is usually expressed as `{x}`, `{x,}`, or `{x,y}`.

Comment: Do you mean "odd" as in "not divisible by two" or "strange"?

Comment: Oops, sorry I can see the confusion, I meant odd as in strange. It has 4 digits of precision for the decimal.

Comment: @user489041 what is the point of matching that "odd" price value if you are not capturing it anyway? Why not just skip it?

Comment: for instance, for the given string, this regex will give you exactly the desired captures: `(.*\S)\s*#\s*(\d{3,4}).*\D(\d*\.\d*)\s+(\d*\.\d*)/day`. But of course, it's a lot less specific about the whole structure of the input. It would help if you told us what can really vary in your input and what parameters have to be the same.

Comment: @m.buettner figured it out, thanks. there was a space that was causing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know `\\d{0,1,2,3...}` is not valid syntax. What you meant was probably:

```
(?:\\$\\s*?\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,4}\\s*?/?day)?
```

Also, are you aware that your whole pattern is optional? This poses a problem. `\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,4}` will only match the first (odd) number. Then you have an optional slash, but a mandatory `day` (if the whole pattern is not dropped). But in your input string there are a few other numbers before `/day` is encountered. So even if it compiles, it won't match your price value. You should probably leave out the `\\s*?/?day` altogether. And think about removing the outer `?`, too. And as Brian stated in the comment, there is no need to make the `\\s` repetition ungreedy, since it and the following element are mutually exclusive anyway:

```
\\$\\s*\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,4}
```

And do you really have to be so specific about the number of digits if the value is "odd" anyway?

```
\\$\\s*\\d*\\.\\d*
```

Comment: Yea, its just a small chunk of a larger one, figure it would be easier for readability. Thanks, let me give that a shot.

Comment: +1, beat me to it :) Also not that `\\s*?` is redundant, `\\s*` is fine by itself.

Comment: I know, but the character after it will never be another whitespace character, so it doesn't matter how greedy it is.

Comment: @m.buettner Sorry, I meant odd as in strange, not as in an odd number. I didn't even realize that.

Comment: @m.buettner Tried your suggestion. 99% there. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

This pattern

`"\\d+\\.\\d{3,}"`

will match every number with more than 2 digits after the dot.